# Adding if statement between Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this block of code in C#, how I can add if statement between Linq statement , before author I need to add if statement to check if CreatedBy is empty or not.

```
     List<Note> notes = apiNotes.Select(x => new Note()
        {
            noteId = x.NoteId,
            date = x.DateEntered.Date.ToString("MMMM dd"),
            time = x.DateEntered.ToString("h:mm tt"),
            body = x.Text,
            title = x.Title,
           //Where I need to add a if statement like If( x.CreatedBy!="")
            author = new Note.Author()
            {  
                fullname = x.CreatedBy ?? "",
                initial = initials.Replace(x.CreatedBy, "$1") ?? ""
            }
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you mean before you assign `author` or before you assign `fullname`?

Comment: Before assigning `author` you can use a ternary expression: `author = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x.CreatedBy) ? null : new Note.Author { …`

Comment: Urm... depending on if you are using an ORM, like EF, you may have a bunch of other problems. however if this is all in memory you should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude any Note that has a null `CreatedBy` field, you just need to add a `Where` section.

```
List<Note> notes = apiNotes
    .Where 
    (
        x => x.CreatedBy != ""
    )
    .Select
    (
        x => new Note()
        {
            noteId = x.NoteId,
            date = x.DateEntered.Date.ToString("MMMM dd"),
            time = x.DateEntered.ToString("h:mm tt"),
            body = x.Text,
            title = x.Title,
            author = new Note.Author()
            {  
                fullname = x.CreatedBy,
                initial = initials.Replace(x.CreatedBy, "$1") ?? ""
            }
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

If you want to include all notes, but leave the `author` property null if there is no value for `CreatedBy`, you can use the ternary operator inline:

```
List<Note> notes = apiNotes
    .Select
    (
        x => new Note()
        {
            noteId = x.NoteId,
            date = x.DateEntered.Date.ToString("MMMM dd"),
            time = x.DateEntered.ToString("h:mm tt"),
            body = x.Text,
            title = x.Title,
            author = x.CreatedBy == null 
                   ? null
                   : new Note.Author()
                     {  
                        fullname = x.CreatedBy,
                        initial = initials.Replace(x.CreatedBy, "$1") ?? ""
                     }
            }
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. This is the standard inline conditional syntax in C#.

```
 List<Note> notes = apiNotes.Select(x => new Note()
    {
        noteId = x.NoteId,
        date = x.DateEntered.Date.ToString("MMMM dd"),
        time = x.DateEntered.ToString("h:mm tt"),
        body = x.Text,
        title = x.Title,
        author = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CreatedBy))
               ? new Note.Author() { fullname = x.CreatedBy, 
                                     initial = initials.Replace(x.CreatedBy, "$1") }
               : null
    }).ToList();
```

But it would make a lot more sense to instead add a constructor  to the Author() class to begin with. `public Note(ApiNote apinote) { ... }`...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this elegantly using the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

```
List<Note> notes = apiNotes.Select(
    x => 
        new Note()
        {
            noteId = x.NoteId,
            date = x.DateEntered.Date.ToString("MMMM dd"),
            time = x.DateEntered.ToString("h:mm tt"),
            body = x.Text,
            title = x.Title,
            author = String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CreatedBy)
                ? null
                : new Note.Author()
                {  
                    fullname = x.CreatedBy,
                    initial = initials.Replace(x.CreatedBy, "$1") ?? ""
                }
        }
).ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You are using the null-coalescing operator `??`, not the conditional operator `? :`, and in this case you are calling it on the result of a .Replace(), which will throw an exception if `initials` is null to begin with, and will never return a `null` itself.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey That was the OP's code so you might want to comment on the question.  Also you're assuming you know what `initials` is and how that specific `Replace` works (it might be a custom class with it's own implementation).